# Does installing anaconda conflict with Python3 and R already installed?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda

On my Ubuntu 18.04, I have Python 3 and R installed. I am about to study some data science, and just found https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/.

anaconda comes with Python and R and some packages. Will installing anaconda conflict with my existing installation of Python 3 and R?

Shall I install anaconda, or shall I install the packages manually and individually on demand?

How do people in data science install the tools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a system python and R as well as anaconda and they don’t seem to conflict and I have the same OS as you.  Conda, the package and environment manager that comes with anaconda, supposedly does not mix well with pip, meaning if you have a virtual environment you should use one or the other.  However, I have mixed them without any difficulties.

I prefer creating virtual environments the more standard way, but there are some scientific packages that are much easier to install using conda.